# What should I do if the keyboard event listener is being used，

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I use the component library, but the Option of the component library already occupies the keyboard event
I tried to add an event to its parent, but it didn't fire

```
    let dom=document.getElementById('ref')
       dom.focus()
       dom.addEventListener('keydown',e=>{
         if(e.keyCode){
           console.log('1')
         }

   })
```

What if I want to add keyboard events
`

```
onKeyDown = (e) => {
   console.log(e)
  };
```

`
I use React, but this method is actually not triggered

Comment: In fact, its keydown is underlined

Comment: are you binding the `onKeyDown` to an element?

Comment: please post a [mcve]